# Postfix internal scheduling of email servers; loadbalancing and use cases

Tags: email, postfix

I've learned about the parameter smtp_randomize_addresses and am curious which use-cases where one would benefit to have the same priority for MX records and allow Postfix to randomly pick email servers for outbound queue management?

I am aware that MX records with the same priority can be used for load balancing - but what happens if smtp_randomize_addresses is disabled in that case?

Additionally, what is the internal scheduling mechanism in Postfix for alternating between forwarding emails in the incoming and deferred queues?